# Why doesn't the chrome dev channel upgrade Chrome via apt-get upgrade anymore?

Tags: apt, upgrade, google-chrome

I was using the Chrome dev channel for a while and was used to getting updates via:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Recently I discovered though that my dev channel remains the same and I have to redownload the [`google-chrome-unstable_current_amd64.deb` from google](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?platform=linux&extra=devchannel) and then an upgrade gets applied via the software center.

How to always get upgrades for Chrome dev channel?

Comment: It updates for me at least once a week.

Comment: @xdevs23 That is the expected behavior, yes :)

Comment: @k0pernikus You might have accidentally removed the Google Chrome entry from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Installing Google Chrome using the deb file from Google makes that entry again.

Comment: @edwinksl I discovered they were uncommented. Thanks. Yet reinstalling the deb file did not change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Due to `apt-key` being deprecated for [reasons](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181/454700), now you should follow the steps as follows:

Set up key:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/google.gpg
```

Set up repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/google.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Setup package with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable
```

Then you can get updates using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

**Old answer:**

From http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable:

Setup key with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Setup package with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable
```

Then you can get updates using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: some warning that apt-key is deprecated, as of Aug 2022

Comment: Thanks for letting know. Here's how to migrate: https://askubuntu.com/a/1398346 | Due to the answer being as old as 2016, this was not accounted for.