# How to solve this W: and N: error message when perform $sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, openvpn

All packages are up to date.

```
W: http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian/dists/bionic/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Comment: @muru A better answer is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407632/key-is-stored-in-legacy-trusted-gpg-keyring-etc-apt-trusted-gpg/1409732#1409732, but even that only solves half of the problem. The other problem is solved by editing a .list file.

Comment: @heynnema you're welcome to post that answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system, since the question is the same

Comment: @muru Already posted a link to it there. My answer is much simpler than the accepted answer there.