# Move keys from legacy trusted.gpg to usr/share/keyrings for Ubuntu sources as well

Tags: apt, gnupg, keys

After warnings about apt-key becoming deprecated and conscientious study on signing files, OpenPgp standard, gpg tool etc. (I'm new to Linux and learning) I've managed to move all my public keys from etc/apt/trusted.d folder to usr/share/keyrings separate files and add [signed-by...] to ppa sources in souces.list.d.

However now I'm trying to do the same for Ubuntu repositories in sources.list file. I've exported listed keys from trusted.gpg file and added [signed-by..] param. Then I deleted trusted.gpg file. The moved key files are in ascii-dearmoured/binary gpg format.

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/Ubuntu-moved-keyring.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
```

But when I run *apt update* I get an error

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy: ...
```

Using Ubuntu system tools I restored defaults and so got the trusted.gpg file back but I'm back to square one - *apt update* complains about the legacy way keys are stored:

```
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

I'm stuck. My understanding is that actually this does not pose any threat of cross-signing sources with another publisher's compromised key since my trusted.gpg file contains only Ubuntu keys but still I'd like to sort the issue.

Comment: I don't believe this is necessary for the Ubuntu keys. The point is, that the Ubuntu keys are in fact trusted, and they should already be under `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`. It's only keys from 3rd party sources that should be moved to `/usr/share/keyrings` and added to repos with a `signed-by` clause. At least this is how I've done it.

Comment: thanks for confirmation - that's what I thought (last paragraph). Can I actually leave them in default location, ie trusted.gpg file and not trusted.gpg.d folder?

Comment: I think the latest apt would very much like you to put the keys in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`. I have two files in there on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

The "hacky" way of solving this is to run:

```
mv /etc/apt/trusted.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
```

This should satisfy `apt`. The more correct way would be to get the official Ubuntu keyfiles again - but I'm actually not aware of the correct procedure for this.

Also see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407632/key-is-stored-in-legacy-trusted-gpg-keyring-etc-apt-trusted-gpg).

Comment: thanks! Looks like worth trying as in trusted.gpg I have only Ubuntu repos keys. However with 3rd party repos I think it wouldn't change much to the overall security since I remember reading on a few pages that trusted.gpg.d and trusted.gpg file are trusted globally on every repo added to the system..

Comment: Did you find a proper way to get the official Ubuntu Keyfiles back? I get " W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease Key is stored in legacy ..." @heynnema was very kind to help me with patience. So far we did not find a solution, see [AU discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149607). It may have been caused by my cleaning of some old keys in "Software & Update". I thought that the important ones can be restored with "Restore Defaults": But I may be wrong.