# Having issues installing Miktex (and compile Latex code)

Tags: apt, latex, visual-studio-code

I believe I have installed Miktex, because when I run `miktex --version` I get `One MiKTeX Utility 1.7 (MiKTeX 23.4)`

However, I cannot run simple latex code. I tried `sudo apt-get update` but surprisenly I got :

```
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/staticfloat/julia-deps/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                               
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                                                   
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                    
Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/staticfloat/julia-deps/ubuntu jammy Release                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease 
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Get:1 https://mirrors.aliyun.com/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb jammy InRelease [2 029 B]
Reading package lists... Done            
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/staticfloat/julia-deps/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Have anyone ever encouter such issue ?
Note that I'm using Latex workshop in Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't know about MikTex, but to use latex in ubuntu, you can install the package `texlive-full`, and use an editor like texstudio. Both are available on the official repositories.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I have also texlive but I cannot compile my latex code in VS studio ; I get the error :  qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
latexmk: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Comment: Try installing vscode as a deb. It seems that you have installed it as snap, which cannot connect to latex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system) and [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/866901/)

Answer (score 0):

The messages given by Apt are not relevant here, it is not implying any issue with your installation of Miktex; there will be some other issue affecting your LaTeX compilation. Here's what they mean:

---

```
Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/staticfloat/julia-deps/ubuntu jammy Release                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
```

The [PPA for providing julia-deps](https://launchpad.net/%7Estaticfloat/+archive/ubuntu/julia-deps) does not support your version of Ubuntu, it hasn't been updated for some time and may be abandoned.
You can remove it with `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:staticfloat/julia-deps` to remove the message, or you can leave it there and the repository might add support but Ubuntu 22 one day. julia-deps is a list of packages used for compiling [Julia](https://julialang.org) on Ubuntu, it's not related to Miktex.

---

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/staticfloat/julia-deps/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

This is a summary of the previous error with julia-deps.

---

```
W: http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

This is a warning about the deprecated method of storing keys insecurely, it won't stop you updating or installing Miktex right now, to resolve the warning follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409732/512236)

---

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

When you have the i386 architecture enabled in Apt, it will check repositories for provided i386 packages, but not all repositories support i386 anymore, so it will generate this message, it won't cause any problems here.

Comment: thank you for a detailed answer. The issue is that when I try to compile a simple code in VS studio I get the error : qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
latexmk: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Comment: @hanava331 Try [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598498/184285) run `sudo apt install qt6-wayland`. It mentions setting the correct environment variable, you may need to do this for launching VSCode itself or it may be part of the build procedure, in which case see some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218695/6530181)