# MySQL how to fix "Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring"?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, mysql, keyrings

For Ubuntu Desktop, after when it was upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, when the `sudo apt update` command is executed arises (fixed in multiple lines):

```
W: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: 
Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), 
see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

How to fix that? The mentioned suggested section in the message is not valuable for guidance about step by step **and** is need it have `MySQL` updated in peace in Ubuntu `22.04` as was accomplished from the beginning at `20.04`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407632/key-is-stored-in-legacy-trusted-gpg-keyring-etc-apt-trusted-gpg)

Comment: Let me test it. I want the 2 parts confirmed. Thanks for the link.