# Ubuntu 22.04 - connection between adapting to apt-key deprecation and Ubuntu Software and Updates (software-properties-gtk)

Tags: apt, repository, gnupg

With Ubuntu 22.04 and beyond, `apt-key` has been deprecated and will eventually be removed.

This creates deprecation messages, so to solve this and attempt to improve security, I followed the following topics:

[What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181)

[Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring after Ubuntu 22.04 update [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403964)

I exported almost all keys from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` to a directory `/usr/share/keyrings` following [the information in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403964):

> This answer is a customization of the one provided by matigo user
> here. You need to export the GPG key from the deprecated keyring and
> store it in `/usr/share/keyrings` for every repo.

This led to exporting many keys from the deprecated keyring into the `/usr/share/keyrings` directory created by me.
For each exported key, I also created/updated its associated three `.list` files, with the list files being stored in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

After that I deleted the keys I exported:

```
sudo apt-key del LAST_8_KEY_DIGITS
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

While `apt-key` throws this recommendation of using the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` directory, [from what I read in this thread answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181) it should be avoided as well:

> All of the answers so far work around the symptom ("Don't use `apt-key add`") but fail to address the actual problem that led to apt-key add
> being deprecated. The problem is not a question of appending a key to
> one big keyring file `etc/apt/trusted.gpg` vs manually putting
> single-key keyring files into the directory `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`.
> These two things are equivalent, and doing either one is a huge
> security risk.
>
> Now that you have your converted key, do not add it to `apt`'s trusted
> keystore by copying it into `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. Instead, put it
> somewhere like `/etc/apt/keyrings/`. (You might need to create that
> keyrings directory first.) There's nothing special about that
> location, it's just a convention recommended by `man 5 sources.list` in
> Ubuntu 22.04 and a related Debian Wiki entry.

So after following those threads and implementing the suggestions, I now have:

- Repository `.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.
- The actual GPG keys in `/usr/share/keyrings`.

I am able to run `apt update` and it correctly hits all the third-party repositories I exported from the deprecated file of `apt-key`.

The question is, is it possible to edit the "Software & Updates" program of Ubuntu (`software-properties-gtk`) to show the GPG keys again?

Not having them in the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` directory or the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` file is better for security from what I understand, but now `software-properties-gtk` cannot list repositories.

In this process of deprecating `apt-key` and improving security, is it possible to point `software-properties-gtk` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and `/usr/share/keyrings` for it to show me the repositories in the "Other Software" tab of the "Software & Updates" GUI?

Grateful for any insight!