# How to install Dropbox without apt-key?

Tags: apt, dropbox, keyrings

Apparently `apt-key` is deprecated because its design contains a security risk.

The solution is to download the key and store it in a location writable only by the root and then to manually create a `sources.list` entry with the `signed-by` option.

For example, to install chrome we can do:

```
sudo wget -O- https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub \
    | gpg --dearmor \
    | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg >> /dev/null
echo deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg] \
    http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list >> /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable -y
```

The problem with this solution is that I cannot find the Dropbox signing key.

[Dropbox help centre](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/linux-repository) mentions a key for *Fedora*, but not Ubuntu:

https://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/rpm-public-key.asc

It all seems quite complicated. Are there some fool-proof, safe, non-deprecated ways to install Dropbox?

Comment: You can install Dropbox as usual (the apt-key deprecation is just a warning, not a blocking error) and then move the key as explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/1398346/1037999