# Post upgrade to 22.04 facing problem with package update

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, held-packages

I recently upgraded to 22.04 and since then I am facing to problems while using command
`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.
Running `sudo apt update` gives me following error about slack key

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:7 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:8 https://downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnol...sie/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

And running `sudo apt upgrade` gives me error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back: 
libapache2-mod-php7.4 libapache2-mod-php8.0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

The command `sudo apt list --upgradable` shows following

```
Listing... Done
libapache2-mod-php7.4/jammy 8.1.2-1ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
libapache2-mod-php8.0/jammy 8.1.2-1ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.18-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
```

I need to upgrade both packages and fix the errors.
Before someone marks it as duplicateThe held packages could not be upgraded with any of following commands
`sudo apt -f install <package>`,
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
`sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: You have repositories from more than one release, this will ofthe give problems or worse. `https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease` and `https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease`  should be disabled. The other non-jammy repos could also give problems.

Comment: Thank you for you response, i triggered me to check/uncheck repositories that where disabled while updating to jammy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system)

Answer (score -1):

Install gnome-software , check for update in gnome-software , It will update all your packages (during system boot).

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This solution works for me, as well as **sudo apt install --only-upgrade** but today, I had 37 packages to update !!!! 37 !!!!