# Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring

Tags: apt, repository, spotify

I added the Spotify Debian Repository to apt and got the following Warning:

```
W: http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

I still was able to install Spotify, but would like to know what this message means and how to fix it.

Comment: [This is the answer you’re looking for](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398346/1222991), I believe 