# source.list file required for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, source-packages

**Getting error while updating ubuntu using command sudo apt-get update**

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/6.0/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-preview/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy/dists/pgadmin4/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details
```

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/ Errors are expected for systems using it; adding it was the mistake (esp. on a 22.04 system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system)