# Can't install amd gpu driver, keep getting weird (seemingly unrelated) error

Tags: apt, amdgpu

I want to install amd proprietary drivers, but whenever I run 'amdgpu-install' I get this error

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Err:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                              
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Hit:3 http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                                        
Ign:4 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                       
Hit:5 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release                   
Hit:7 http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease   
Hit:8 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.1/ubuntu jammy InRelease     
Hit:9 http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease
Hit:10 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.4.1 jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu kinetic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

I previously downloaded (and deleted) anbox. I have no idea why these error messages have anbox in them even though it's not in my computer anymore. I've also tried 'amdgpu-install -y' with the same result

system info:

```
  Kernel: 5.19.0-31-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME v: 43.1
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: B450 GAMING PLUS (MS-7B86) v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1.E0
    date: 06/11/2020
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 2700 bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache: L2: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2733 min/max: 1550/3200 cores: 1: 1732 2: 3275 3: 3473
    4: 3403 5: 3486 6: 1404 7: 1399 8: 3475 9: 1849 10: 3485 11: 3482 12: 3468
    13: 3514 14: 1402 15: 1403 16: 3490
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3 driver:
    X: loaded: amdgpu unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 2560x1440~144Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 5700 (navi10 LLVM 15.0.2 DRM 3.47
    5.19.0-31-generic) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 10 HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: FiiO K3 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio
  Device-4: C-Media Blue Snowball type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-31-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlo1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    driver: r8169
  IF: enp34s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 2.1
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.52 GiB used: 457.48 GiB (49.1%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.89 GiB used: 138.78 GiB (30.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 30.4 MiB (6.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 1.48 GiB (74.1%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 71.4 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 70.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: amdgpu fan: 747
Repos:
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
    1: deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic main restricted
    2: deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates main restricted
    3: deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic universe
    4: deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates universe
    5: deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic multiverse
    6: deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates multiverse
    7: deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    8: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security main restricted
    9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security universe
    10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-proprietary.list
    1: deb https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.1/ubuntu jammy proprietary
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu.list
    1: deb https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.1/ubuntu jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list
    1: deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/morphis-ubuntu-anbox-support-kinetic.list
    1: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu/ kinetic main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.4.1 jammy main
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party *personal package archives* and security checks are on you to perform, ie. did you check and see that PPA wasn't deleted by it's owner?

Comment: FYI:   Sources & packages are different things, you talk about downloading & removing `anbox` which sounds like you're talking about a *package*, but your errors show issues with sources (*not packages*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system)