# sudo apt warnings after upgrade

Tags: apt, updates, repository

After upgrade to 20.04 I get the following W warnings:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
W: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

keys for these bionic/InRelease repos are not listed in the keys when I list them so I can't delete them if I don't know the key digits to delete.

I get the same error preventing me from using synaptic to manage packages.

I would be grateful for suggestions as to how to solve this.

Ideally what to type into terminal.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system)

Comment: Yes, I already tried this but unfortunately, keys for archive/bionic/InRelease are not listed in the keys when I try that option so I can't delete them if I don't know the key digits to delete.

Comment: Seems something went wrong during upgrade to 20.04 (focal). You shouldn't use bionic repos if you upgraded to focal.

Comment: Yes I get that - so is there a way to find these archive keys from the previous distribution and delete them so that these warning messages don't appear any more?