# sudo apt-get update gives gpg keyring warning messages

Tags: 22.04, gnupg

**System details**

OS  - Ubuntu 22.04

**Problem**

I am running the command `sudo apt-get update` on my Ubuntu 22.04 in the terminal. But I am getting the gpg keyring warning messages as follows

```
W: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

[Here's the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3CJf.png)

**Expected Result**
I was expecting to get  fetched the latest version of the package list from my distro's software repository, and any third-party repositories that may have configured.

**Results I got**
I am getting `Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.` warning messages.

**Solutions Tried** -
I tried the solution from this [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system) but when I delete the key from Step 5 , i get the new Error as

```
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

Here's the image for new error [public key is not available error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7qAH.png)