# how to prevent *.list files from getting overwritten?

Tags: apt, ppa, gnupg

Following the accepted answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system) question, I have adjusted the ppa entry for [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en) to the following entry:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/geogebra.gpg] http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main
```

This works very well, however occasionally the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/geogebra.list seems to get overwritten and reverted to the old version:

```
deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main
```

When is this file overwritten?
How can I prevent this, without reducing the security level (meaning: I want the particular key to be usable only for the particular ppa and software)?

I am on (K)Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: Please share an example who the overwritten file looks like. Any idea when the overwritting happens? After running `apt update`. Please also add details on which Ubuntu release you are using.

Comment: @noisefloor I have adjusted the question to include the requested information. I have not yet identified when this happens, though it is not after running `apt update`.

Comment: It's possible one of the packages from this repository thinks it owns that file and tries to overwrite it instead of treating it as a conffile. Usually I'd call that a packaging bug and file a bug report with the maintainers. Check the postinst files of the packages you have installed from that repo.

Comment: @muru Thank you. Can you give be a pointer were to find those?

Comment: The postinst files are in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`. Maybe try something like `grep geogebra.list /var/lib/dpkg/info/ -R --include='*.postinst'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working around the problem:

You can make the file immutable:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/geogebra.list
```

You can change the file name to `geogebra-classic.list`. The other file will provide a warning when using `apt`.

But to solve the root cause of the problem you need to check the running script on your system, crontab, custom systemd services...

Comment: @Bruni Oh my bad. It is `chattr +i`. Yes it will work. But the clean solution is to found the script causing this problem.

Comment: @Bruni I am writing from a smartphone. The autocorrect make my post unreadable.

Comment: No  problem, I adjusted the command as you intended it to be written. This will definitely help a lot. I will also contact geogebra and maybe they will adjust the intstructions.

Comment: @Bruni This tuto may be helpful to track file changes https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html